# how to load jquery and other javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first time using lightbox which uses jquery framework. But when I paste jQuery and Lightbox javascript files into my html page, my current javascript code doesn't work properly. Is the way I set them up wrong? Thank you. This is the order I put my js files

the error I got is:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734
Edit:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="random.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="load-poll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

And this is the beginning of my own js file as the page loads:

```
var POLL_WIDTH = 200;
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    if ($("favChar")){
        fetchPoll("favChar");
    }else if ($("favVoice")){
        fetchPoll("favVoice");
    }else if ($("CMTvote")){
        fetchPoll("CMTvote");
    }else if ($("BLdesign")){
        fetchPoll("BLdesign");
    }
});
```

Comment: that code seems like prototype...

Comment: What other javascript libraries are you using on the page? more  than likely jQuery is conflicting with them.

Comment: sorry, I also use prototype. I edit the part about my js files above

Comment: probably a conflict between prototype and jquery. try turning off (commenting) the prototype and use jquery instead. Use $(document).ready or $(function) instead of document.observe

Comment: @kaboom ... This probably isn't an option for you. But you should take a look at colorbox sometime. It has event hooks that make what you are trying to do pretty simple. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox Also maybe try wrapping your code in jQuery noconflict... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
$(function() {
  // your init code
});
```

instead of

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // your init code
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed both of my own js files to use $(function() { but only 1 of them works properly. the other still report error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' prototype.js:5734

Comment: can you post the code from your other js file? It may be using something from prototype that could be changed to use jquery too. (you may also vote the useful answers ;) )

Comment: hi, thanks. I gt it working now. I replace the $ sign with jQuery